# What exactly Google backup for restoring Android app from Google backup?

Tags: android, restore

I have created an app that  receives several credentials via Rest Api on successful authorization. Those credentials are directly used in App. On restoring Android App from Google backup, does it also restore all those credentials or else , it will behave like  as a new installed app.

Comment: Are these credentials strored somewhere?

Comment: i am storing them in a variable inside code once i receive them via Rest. I wanted App to ask those credentails from rest on every new installation after authentication.

Comment: I don't know, but suppose it makes sense only for saved data. If you keep them in memory in runtime, I can't understand how they could be backed up.

Comment: Google backup covers files, not application in-memory states.